# Android CardView issue on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, xml

Hi I've been working on this app for about a month, today I decided to test it out on pre-lollipop devices and I'm getting diferent results when the CardView is showed. Here's a image of the results [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNK6O.jpg)

And here's my xml layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/CardViewCustom"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/listRestaurantContainer"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
card:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_cardview_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@id/progress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/squareReview"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/review_square" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/CardViewText.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingStart="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        style="@style/CardViewText.Category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingStart="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        style="@style/CardViewText.Address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgWrapper"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingStart="6dp" />

</RelativeLayout></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Please post your layout in the question itself. Please don't link to it off-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some way it was creating a CardView inside another CardView, came up with a fix and solved the issue.